# How deserialize JSON object from HttpResponse using Jackson annotations?

Tags: java, json, jackson, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using the Apache http classes to call a web service that returns a JSON object in the response body. I have a Jackson annotated java class mapped to the JSON object. I want to do something this, but google hasn't turned up the correct boilerplate.

```
    String url = hostName + uri;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject)response.getEntity().getContent();
```

Comment: Reading the documentation helps: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You have to use the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.4/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html):

```
MyObject myObject = objectMapper.readValue(response.getEntity().getContent(), MyObject.class);
```

(An object mapper instance can be reused, so no need to create a new one for each deserialization)

Comment: All Jackson methods have form 'readValue(source, type)', so it kind of follows pattern. And when using IDE, auto-completion helps a lot showing possibilities (if not, need to check javadocs)

Comment: Getting "Non-static method 'readValue(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.Class<T>)' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Wow I'm a noob I just had to do `ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();` first