# How to store variable from API call in java

Tags: java, httpclient

```
public void getToken(String userID) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URIBuilder userBuild = new URIBuilder("https://api/token");
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(userBuild.build());
    printPost(post);
}

public void printPost(HttpPost post) throws IOException {

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
}
```

So, what I want to achieve is that I would like to save the "token" as a variable.

For example, when I run the method, "getToken()", it prints out like:
{"token": "1234567" } on the console.

However, how sould I save that "1234567"? Is it related to something like getHeaders()?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing the response you should parse it as JSON and store this value in a variable:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624801/5790043
You can use [Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20058513/5790043) or [Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6949366/5790043) libraries for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to have a look at serialization and deserialization. In this case, you want to deserialize your JSON output and turn it into a Java Object. This way you can easily have access to anything you want regarding your response.

A common way to do this in Java is by using the Jackson ObjectMapper. Try to turn your response into a Java object and get the value you need.